# find date nearest to target in a list of dates

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a list of Date objects, and a target Date. I want to find the date in the list that's nearest to the target date, but only dates that are after the target date.

Example: `2008-10-1` `2008-10-2` `2008-10-4`

With a target date of `2008-10-3`, I want to get `2008-10-4`

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: TargetDate is separate field or you can store all date in single fields ?

Comment: What did you try so far? Pls include a code example.

Comment: Based on your tag, you're trying to do this in `AMPScript` in the SF Marketing Cloud, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list of dates, read through it and then stop as soon as you get to a date that is >= the one you want.

```
list<Date> dates = new list<Date>();

//add all the dates;

dates.sort();

//now the list is ordered from oldest date to newest
```

Comment: I believe he's looking for an `AMPScript` solution.

Comment: doh! I need to read more carefully next time...

Answer (score -1):

Dominic's answer is the smartest way. Here is another way

```
List<Date> dateList = new List<Date>();

dateList.add(Date.Today()+1);
dateList.add(Date.Today()-2);
dateList.add(Date.Today()-1);

Date target = Date.today();
Integer days = 100000000;
Date nearest = target;
Integer count = 0;
do{
    Date d = dateList.get(count);
    if(d>target && days>target.daysBetween(d))
    {

            days = target.daysBetween(d);
            nearest = d;
    }
    count++;
}while(count < dateList.size());
System.debug('nearest'+nearest.day());
```

Comment: Ampscript has sort function?

Comment: Where did I use sort function?

Comment: There isn't a sort function in `AMPScript`.

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice it! I don't have much expertise in AMPScript.